# Unable to create mysql table Dynamically

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a page where a user inputs data for an advertisement and after taking inputs it creates a table where data can be stored . Data being passed correctly and a way to always ensure the table name generated will be unique.

But I am unable to get the query executed and having no idea that why its not working.

I am a beginner and hence any advice at all would be much appreciated.

My code is given below

```html
$Tablename = $Title.$Mobileno;
echo $Tablename;
$sqltable = "CREATE TABLE $Tablename ( `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `Title` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , `Sname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `descrip` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL , `mno` INT(30) NOT NULL , `base` INT(30) NOT NULL , `cutoff` INT(30) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)) ENGINE = InnoDB";
mysqli_query($con,$sqltable);
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sqltable))
{echo "TABLE NOT MADE ";}
$sql = "INSERT INTO $Tablename(Title,Sname,email,descrip,mno,base,cutoff)VALUES('$Title','$Sname','$email','$Description','$Mobileno','$Base','$Cutoff')";
mysqli_query($con,$sqltable);
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{echo'not inserted';}
else {echo'inserted';}


?>
```

Comment: Why you need to create a table on every input record. Why not you can save all input data in one table with different IDs or time spams ?

Comment: i need for each ad to be like an individual profile because i need for it in the end to have its own page . for example if you click on an ad for a car , it needs to redirect to a webpage made just to fully show the ad for the car which will enlist all the details which cannot be shown in the search results page .

Comment: Well, I am sure you can do like this, make a single table and add all input data in that. In list page, show few fields manually and on detail page you can show all fields and also add some design layout. 

As per my knowledge, creating a new table on every ad record is not a good idea. Memory Issue, Time Issue, Data Management Issue

Comment: i completely agree with your point . the only reason i chose to do that is because i want the site to work as seamlessly as possible which is why i wanted the table to be created dynamically . thus , adding 4 to 5 lines of code would automatically create a basic template which would self adjust the information to create individual pages for each ad , just like individual facebook profiles . thats the only issue i have and i am unable to find any workaround in that

Comment: Hmmm ok then you can try the @scaisEdge's suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Try enciosing with quote the tablename

```
 "CREATE TABLE '$Tablename'  (
       `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT 
     , `Title` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL 
     , `Sname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL 
     , `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
     , `descrip` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL 
     , `mno` INT(30) NOT NULL 
     , `base` INT(30) NOT NULL 
     , `cutoff` INT(30) NOT NULL 
     , PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)) ENGINE = InnoDB";
```

or use string concatenation

```
      "CREATE TABLE '" . $Tablename."'  (
       `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT 
     , `Title` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL 
     , `Sname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL 
     , `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
     , `descrip` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL 
     , `mno` INT(30) NOT NULL 
     , `base` INT(30) NOT NULL 
     , `cutoff` INT(30) NOT NULL 
     , PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)) ENGINE = InnoDB";
```

be sure you have proper sanitize the $Tablename vars